# Checking argument count and adjusting input argument value to default

Tags: bash

I have a command line program where I want to check if argument is 2 or 3.

```sh
if [ $# -eq 2 ] || [$# -eq 3]; then
....
fi
```

Is this above a valid comparison?

If input argument is 2 then I need to forcefully have $2 set to a defined value and $3 as $2 entered by the user.

```sh
if [$# -eq 2]; then
    $# = 3
    $3 = $2
    $2 = "c1"
fi
```

Is this a valid assignment?

Comment: yes, the comparison is fine. Didn't you check it?

Comment: How can I change the total number of arguments $#?

Comment: can you please give an example.. like I showed above if $# is 2 and I want to manually make it 3, can i assign it as $#=3 ?

Comment: Better clarify your question. The arguments you are getting are as they are. You can load them into a variable, etc, but changing the original arguments seems to be a bit strange.

Comment: I think the builtin command, set may be used to "artificially" change the positional parameters from inside the script or function. I am trying to achieve something similar.. But couldn't find a proper example.

Comment: Yes `set` can change the positional parameters. `set -- new1 new2 new3 ...`.

Comment: Note that `[$# -eq 2]` is missing needed spaces: `[ $# -eq 2 ]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.. but somehow the logical OR operation is not taking 3 arguments. The script should accept either 2 or 3 arguments. It works fine with 2 arguments but when I give 3 arguments it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set` command to explicitly set the positional parameters. Note that `$#` is updated automatically; you don't need to (nor can you) set it explicitly.

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    set -- "$1" fixed-value "$2"
fi
```